# Что лучше: temporary table или truncate?

Tags: sql, mysql

Довольно часто формирую таблицы "на лету" для вывода в браузер. Иногда очень удобно делать сортировки или группировки средствами SQL. Также бывают ситуации, что таблицы абсолютно однотипные каждый раз.

Лучше делать временную таблицу?

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table
```

или один раз создать

```
CREATE TABLE temp_table
```

а затем, после вывода, стирать содержимое?

```
TRUNCATE temp_table
```

Я, конечно, подозреваю блокировку таблицы при большом количестве запросов при втором подходе, но чем лучше временная таблица, если для нее также используется одно и тоже имя всякий раз?

P.S. вариант создания временной таблицы с переменным именем использую при необходимости.

Comment: Может в вашем случае, можно было бы использовать "представление" (VIEW). Или вы не рассматриваете такой вариант?

Comment: тоже с трудом понимаю зачем после каждой выборки делать транкейт. согласен с @Deonis, пожалуй лучше создать много вью на все случаи жизни

Comment: временная таблица формируется каким-нибудь скриптом, например php, каждый раз с новыми параметрами выборки из нескольких десятков постоянных таблиц, пересчетами различных показателей и другой группировкой полей. думаю, view тут не подходит.

Comment: Может я до конца не понял вас, но зачем вам двойная работа, ведь как то вы получаете выборку, далее вы вставляете ее во временную таблицу, а потом из нее выводите. Не проще ли генерировать запросы на основе ваших условий выборок и прочего

Answer (score 1):

Вы похоже и не знаете, что результатом работы **любого** SQL запроса/скрипта всегда является SQL таблица - в чем и суть реляционной БД. Таблица может и не быть оформлена в виде `CREATE TABLE`, но она есть все равно.

Вам же уже ответил [@ЫЫЫ](/users/7285/%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B)

> Может я до конца не понял вас, но
> зачем вам двойная работа, ведь как то
> вы получаете выборку, далее вы
> вставляете ее во временную таблицу, а
> потом из нее выводите. Не проще ли
> генерировать запросы на основе ваших
> условий выборок и прочего

Полностью с ним согласен - фтопку временные таблицы!

Comment: вы меня всё-таки плохо понимаете или я уж совсем плохо излагаю. если бы всё ограничивалось SQL запросом, то конечно никакого вопроса о временных таблицах не стояло. 

я же пишу "формируется скриптом из нескольких десятков таблиц", то есть множество данных в какой-то момент хранится в массивах php, которые я не хочу сортировать, группировать и тп. и именно эту сборную солянку я и выгружаю во временную таблицу, к которой затем и делаю необходимый запрос.

Answer (score 0):

Временная таблица размещается в памяти. Выгода от временных таблиц есть если вы делаете `CREATE TEMPRORY TABLE ... SELECT` - то есть не вытягиваете промежуточные данные в php, а всю подготовку делаете внутри sql сервера.

Была у меня однажды такая задача где было с десяток таких запросов подготавливающих данные во временной таблице, а уже потом скопом вытягивающих результат. Если делать каждый раз `truncate` на обычной таблице то тогда никакой выгоды нет, поэтому думаю `TEMPORARY` в вашем случае лучше - хотя все надо пробовать, сразу вам никто не скажет ;)

Answer (score 0):

Временная таблица доступна только текущему пользователю в рамках сессии. Поэтому не возникает коллизий с запросами других пользователей, как в случае постоянной таблицы. Поэтому постоянные таблицы для промежуточных вычислений - страшное зло.
Временные таблицы помогают в случае выборки большого массива данных потом нескольких подвыборок на основе этих данных. Например, отобрали перечень товаров на складе по нескольким хитрым фильтрам, сохранили во временную таблицу, а затем на ее основе построили запросы о количестве этих товаров всех вместе, в разрезе по местам хранения, структуру дерева "группа-товар", уникальный перечень реквизитов выбранных товаров. Все эти выборки можно делать отдельно, каждый раз соединяя с первоначальным отбором товара. Но проходить по уже выбранным товарам гораздо быстрее.